# Determine on what page a record is

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, pagination, offset

How can I determine on what page a certain record is?

Let's say i display 5 records per page using a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,5
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5,5
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10,5
```

Sample data:

```
id  | name | date
-----------------------------------------------------
1   | a    | 2013-11-07 08:19               page 1
2   | b    | 2013-12-02 12:32
3   | c    | 2013-12-14 14:11
4   | d    | 2013-12-21 09:26
5   | e    | 2013-12-22 18:52      _________ 
6   | f    | 2014-01-04 11:20               page 2
7   | g    | 2014-01-07 21:09
8   | h    | 2014-01-08 13:39
9   | i    | 2014-01-08 16:41
10  | j    | 2014-01-09 07:45      _________
11  | k    | 2014-01-14 22:05               page 3
12  | l    | 2014-01-21 17:21
```

Someone may edit a record, let's say with `id = 7`, or insert a new record (`id = 13`). How can determine on which page is that record? The reason is that I want to display the page that contains the record that has just been edited or added.

ok I guess I could just display the same page if the record is edited. But the problem is when a record gets added. The list can be ordered by name and the new record could be placed anywhere :(

Is there some way I could do a query like `SELECT offset WHERE id = 13 ORDER BY date LIMIT 5` that returns 10 ?

Comment: What does `date` record?  That's a **terrible** name for a column - it's only descriptive of the type, not what's important - the information contained.  For instance if it's really `updatedAt`, I'd assume the page would `page 1`.... (unless frequency of updates is too quick, in which case you have pagination problems regardless).  Otherwise, you have to order all pages (based on whatever), assign a rank (place in page), then find what the rank (and thus page) the given entry is on.  If your set of entries is large this can be expensive...  OLAP functions/CTEs help, but...

Comment: it's `createdAt`, not `updatedAt`. I don't understand how do ranks help if I have to get the entire set anyway :s

Comment: I'm talking about OLAP functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()`, which is what's known as a "windowing function" (SQLite doesn't appear to have this feature, though).  The function assigns an incrementing number based on the specified order, which can then be used to return offsets and stuff.  Although, thinking about this, there's another solution possible here... writing answer...

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of this example, let's assume that entry `7` has just been added (and that there could be duplicate names) - the first thing you need to do is find how many entries come before that one (based on `name`), thus:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Posts
WHERE name <= 'g'
      AND id < 7
```

Here, `id` is being used as a "tiebreaker" column, to ensure a stable sort.  It's also assuming that we know the value of `id`, too - given that non-key data can be duplicate, you **need** that sort of functionality.
In any case, this gives us the number of rows preceding this one (6).  With some integer division arithmetic (based on the `LIMIT`), we can now get the relevant information:

```
(int) ((6 - 1) / 5) = 1
```

... this is for a 0-indexed page, though (ie, entries 1 - 5 appear on page "0"); however, in this case it works in our favor.  Note that we have to subtract 1 from the initial count because the first is 1, *not* 0 - otherwise, entry 5 would appear on the second page, instead of the first.
We now have the *page* index, but we need to turn it into the *entry* index.  Some simple multiplication does that for us:

```
(1 * 5) + 1 = 6
```

(ignore that this is identical to the count - it's coincidence in this case).
This gives us the index of the first entry on the page, the value for `OFFSET`.
We can now write the query:

```
SELECT id, name, date
FROM Posts
ORDER BY name, id
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 6
```

(keep in mind that we *require* `id` to guarantee a stable sort for the data, if we assume that `name` could be a duplicate!).
This is two trips to the database.  Surprisingly, SQLite allows `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` values to be the results of SQL subqueries (keep in mind, not all RDBMSs allow them to even be *host variables*, meaning the could only be changed with dynamic SQL.  Although in at least one case, the db had `ROW_NUMBER()` to make up for that...).  I wasn't able to get rid of the repetition of the subqueries, though.

```sql
SELECT Posts.id, Posts.name, Posts.date, Pages.pageCount
FROM Posts
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ((COUNT(*) - 1) / 5) + 1 as pageCount 
      FROM Posts
      WHERE name < 'g' or (name = 'g' AND id < 7)) Pages
ORDER BY name, id
LIMIT 5 OFFSET (SELECT ((COUNT(*) - 1) / 5) * 5 as entryCount 
      FROM Posts
      WHERE name < 'g' or (name = 'g' AND id < 7))
```

(and the working [SQL Fiddle example](https://sqlfiddle.com/sqlite/online-compiler?id=68f5ccf8-cb65-4eb7-ac49-9081579f3b70)).

Comment: How the `ORDER BY` is taken into account in this case? The topic starter mentioned `ORDER BY date`.

Comment: What about if the data is like below (sorted by name): `id = 10, name = 'a', id = 20, name = 'b', id = 1, name = 'c',`

Comment: In the case of this answer, I was doing the ordering based on the (apparent) requirement that the page was being sorted by name, rather than last update.  There is an `ORDER BY` statement in the overall result.

Comment: But then the suggested approach is not versatile? Let's say I have a word `window` which has `id = 10`, and 100 words started from `a`, `b`, `c` etc which have `ids` from 11 to 111. After applying the `ORDER BY word` the `window` will be somewhere in the bottom (Xth page) but using your `WHERE word <= 'window' AND id < 10` will count only `9` (i.e. 1st page) that is not correct. Could you please to advise what to do?

Comment: @BambinoUA - Yes, you are completely correct.  I had an error in my conditions that has now been corrected.